# C using dig in ubuntu DNS

Tags: c, ubuntu, dns, dig

I'm trying to make a DNS in Ubuntu and sometimes I have to use the dig command(I'm using test=system("dig www.google.com")
How can I get the IPv4 from the return of the dig command to them be able to use it?

Comment: Using `system`? You can't. Try [`popen`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/popen.3.html) instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean "make a DNS lookup"? If so, try the functions `gethostbyname` and `gethostbyaddr`. This is much more efficient than `dig`.

Or do you specifically want the output of `dig`? If so, use `popen()`.